# Sympy plot show wrong calues of y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I was solving a problem using sympy in Visual Studio Code, the y-axis has wrong values as you can see in the attached picture.

I calculated the graphed function at x = 0, and the value is 2.9 * 10^-15, while the value on the graph is 2.9 which is wrong.

How to adjust the graph so that it represent the true values ?

---

```
result[0] = -1.57105971754913e-10*x**14 + 1.57271456119008e-10*x**13 + 2.50455430685362e-8*x**12 - 2.50462325622519e-8*x**11 - 2.75572538491514e-6*x**10 + 2.75572653284313e-6*x**9 + 0.000198412694745413*x**8 - 0.000198412695713169*x**7 - 0.00833333333219247*x**6 + 0.0083333333326227*x**5 + 0.166666666666487*x**4 - 0.166666666666582*x**3 - 0.999999999999986*x**2 + 0.999999999999997*x - 2.92499929794508e-15
```

[image]

Comment: please share `results[0]`?

Comment: We aren't seeing the whole plot image here.  Usually there will be a notation saying that the values are `x10^-15`.

Comment: @Davide_sd, I attached it now.

Comment: @TimRoberts then how to show the whole plot image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot is perfectly fine: you can see the `10^-15` on the top left corner of the plot. It is just that you are using a dark theme with VSCode and matplotlib returns a PNG picture with a transparent figure, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: Oh. I didn't expect that :'). Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe `plot1 = plot(...);  backend = plot1.backend(plot1);
backend.fig.set_facecolor('white')` would work here?